# How to free leaking memory after opening files using FILE *?

Tags: c

So, I am suffering a memory leak! Here is the program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int b, char** locations) {

    struct pair* table[size];
    createTable(table);
    int look = 0;

    FILE * textFile;

    look = 1;
    int doing = 0;
   
    while (locations[look] != NULL) {
        textFile = fopen(locations[2], "r");
        //textFile = fopen(locations[look], "r");
        look++;
        doing++;
        //free(textFile);
    }


}
```

According to valgrind there are 2 leaks how do i solve this? the program takes input in the form of `./main -12 folder/example.txt folder/example2.txt...`

attempting to free each `FILE *` doesn't work it causes the program to run infinitely.
also keep in mind this is just a code snippet this is my MRE and where I narrowed the leak(s) down to.

Comment: Are u still encountering that even if you call `fclose()` ?

Comment: would i do fclose() inside the loop?

Comment: would you be willing to show me what you mean?

Comment: You should `fclose()` once you are done processing your file.So after the loop,judging from the code.

Comment: you helped me solve the issue all that was needed was the fclose(textFile) inside the loop

Comment: May I suggest that you only open the file once, before the loop since the name `locations[2]` remains constant?

Comment: The first leak is from not closing your file, and the second is probably from not freeing the list of pointers (`createTable(table);`)

Answer (score 1):

`textfile` cannot be `free()`d, but you can `fclose()` it, and all the internal memory allocated to run it will be deallocated by stdio library.

You cannot free the memory that has been *leaked*, because the meaning of leak comes from the impossibility of getting the reference of the address where it was allocated.  You have overwritten the pointer you had with the address of that memory and now you don't have any means to locate that memory in your virtual address space.